# Targeting Multiple Resolutions Using Flex 4.5

Tags: android, actionscript-3, apache-flex, mobile, flex4.5

I'm developing a game for Android tablets using Flash Builder 4.5.  It has been implemented successfully on Galaxy Tab 7.0", but now I need to edit it in order to fit all android tablets. I attempted searching for information on this, but nothing I found was useful.

Should I use multiple graphics to target devices with different resolutions and, if so, how then should I detect the correct resolution?  Or, on the other hand, should I use just one graphic and scale it to fit all resolutions required?

I would also appreciate any good tutorials specifically for games rather than applications, if there are any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use vector-based graphics that will look sharp at different densities. See [Adobe's article](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/mobile-skinning-part2.html) on the matter.

Alternatively, you can use different graphic sources for each bitmap depending on resolution. From the same article:

```
<s:Button>
    <s:icon>
        <s:MultiDPIBitmapSource
            source160dpi="@Embed('/assets/refresh160.png')"
            source240dpi="@Embed('/assets/refresh240.png')"
            source320dpi="@Embed('/assets/refresh320.png')"/>
    </s:icon>
</s:Button>
```

Note that the icon on this button has a different graphic depending on each platform's native pixel density. This makes the application heavier, but if you don't have a ton of graphics (and your images are optimized for size), you should be fine.